# let a html button call a Controller Action

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I make my html Button

(like  `<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">delete</button>`)

call a Controller Action like `deleteAction($project)`
from within my twig code?(or with java script)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In twig template

```
<a href="{{ path('delete_route_name', {'id': entity.id }) }}">Delete</a>
```

On your controller

```
/**
 * @param User $entity
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/entity-remove", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="delete_route_name")
 * @return RedirectResponse
 *
 */
public function deleteActionName(User $entity)
...
```

Answer (score 5):

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages

```
<a href="{{ path('deleteRouteName') }}">Home</a>
```

Comment: how would this call the action? and how does it get my parameter?

Comment: please see the documentation. you define the route which takes a parameter, then you can give this paremter to the path like `path('deleteRouteName', {'id': project.id}) }}`