# Symfony4 button in twig to call function in a controller doesn't work

Tags: controller, twig, symfony4

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384627/let-a-html-button-call-a-controller-action) to create a button to call a function but it is not working.
No error message and the redirect works. But the order status doesn't change....
Can anyone find what is the wrong with it?

my button in twig

```
<a href="{{ path('change_order_status', { id : NewOrder.id }) }}" class="btn btn-primary">change status</a>
```

my controller

```
    /**
     * @param order $target
     *
     * @Route("/admin/order", name="change_order_status")
     */
    public function changeOrderStatus(order $target)
    {
        echo dump($target);
        if (!$target instanceof Order) {
         return;
        }
        $OrderStatus = $this->orderStatusRepository->find(OrderStatus::IN_PROGRESS);
        $target->setOrderStatus($OrderStatus);
        $target->setOrderDate(new \DateTime());
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();         
        $em->persist($Order);         
        $em->flush(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'is not working'? Please show some error messages or explain what the expected and actual behaviour is.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't show error messages, and the redirecting works but the OrderStatus doesn't change.

Comment: Did you persist and flush?

Comment: thank you. I forgot it. I put `$em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($Order);
        $em->flush();`  in bottom of the function still doesn't work and no error message appeared .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple flaws in the code:

- Your controller has no redirection (not even a response) so if the code is complete, the redirection you see won't come from Symfony.
- the action parameter `$target` is type-hinted with `order` but the object is of type `Order` (case matters!)

  - when the type-hint is correct, the `instanceof` check if redundant
- you are persisting `$Order` but not `$target` so the variable name is wrong